# Read from a text file to object vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
void Admin::searchFlight(string destination)
{
    Flight sFlight;
    string read;
    ifstream inFlight("Flight.txt");
    while(getline(inFlight, read))
    {
        flightList.push_back(sFlight);
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < flightList.size(); i++)
    {
        if(destination.compare(flightList[i].getDestination()))
        {
            //counter++;
            flightList[i].displayFlightSchedule();
        }
    }
}
```

There is some data inside the text file, how do I read the text file inside the vector?
This is my overloading constructor `Flight()`:

```
Flight flightSchedule(flightID,departure,destination,price,dateOfFlight,timeOfFlight);
```

and here is my vector declaration:

```
vector<Flight> flightList;
```

Comment: You may override `operator>>()`

Comment: Define an `istream` extractor for `Flight`, and parse each line through a `std::istringstream`wrapping the line-just-read in your main loop. assuming that is, it is one-flight-per-line in the file format.

Comment: Btw, I dont see any question here. You need to parse a string into your object?

Comment: The problem is the cmd will pop out the default value to me but not the value from the text file.

Comment: what is the content of each line of your file?

Comment: @sshilovsky: You meant _overload_, not _override_: the latter has to do with virtual functions.

Comment: Right, _overload_ `operator>>()`

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements, assuming your Flight.txt content is:

India 22

USA 23

China 24

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

void searchFlight(string);

class Flight
{
  public:
  string destination;
  int tm;

  Flight(string d, int t):destination(d), tm(t)
  {
  }

  string getDestination()
  {
     return destination;
  }

  int displayFlightSchedule()
  {
    return tm;
  }

};


int main()
{
   searchFlight("India");
   return 0;
}

void searchFlight(string destin)
{
   vector<Flight> flightlist;

   string line;
   int tm;
   string dest;

   ifstream ifs("Flight.txt");

   while(getline(ifs, line))
   {
     istringstream is(line);
     is>>dest>>tm;

     flightlist.push_back(Flight(dest, tm));

   }

   for(unsigned i = 0; i<flightlist.size(); i++)
   {
     if (destin == (flightlist[i].getDestination()))
     {
       cout<<flightlist[i].displayFlightSchedule()<<endl;
     }
   }
 }
```

**OUTPUT:**

22